# Content in String is modified when using PrepareStatement in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

currently I want to insert a string which contains a lot of special characters into mysql database, thus I use PrepareStatement in java.

> My sql command:

```
 String st = "INSERT INTO SET (ID,AUTHOR,TEXT) VALUES (?,?,?)";
 PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(st);
 stm.setString(1, ID);
 stm.setString(2, author);
 stm.setString(3, text);
 System.out.println(text);*
 System.out.println(stm.toString());**
```

The problem is that when I use setString method, my string's content was modified. 

The original string's content*:

> Why do organisms evolve in the manner that they do‭? ‬Are there
>   restrictions or constraints that influence the direction of
>   evolutionary change‭? ‬Although in‭ ‬1917‭ ‬D’Arcy Thompson stated
>   that‭...

The string's content when added to PreparedStatement by setString method**:

> INSERT INTO SET (ID,AUTHOR,TEXT) VALUES
>   (1693,'Ws','Why do organisms evolve in
>   the manner that they do?? ?Are there restrictions or constraints that
>   influence the direction of evolutionary change?? ?Although in? ?1917?
>   ?D’Arcy Thompson stated that...

I have no idea why there are '?' marks occur in the string's content..... 

Can someone help me? Thank you very much.

P/S: The string in the database is the modified string with '?' mark.

Comment: 1. Why aren't you using `setXXX()` to set `ID` and `author` too?    2. Why do you think your string has changed? Does it look ok in the db?

Comment: How you are reading the text variable? Is it from a file or something?

Comment: Where are you seeing this string? Is it the result of stm.toString()? If so, that's not what you should care about. What you should care about is the value inserted in the database. Also, ID and author should also be parameters of the statement.

Comment: To start with, you're using prepared statements wrong; you should be using placeholders for the author and ID as well. Furthermore, a prepared statement *isn't* a string, and have you tried actually executing it to see what gets inserted into the database?

Comment: Ignore statement.toString() which might be misleading and look to database, how it was stored

Comment: The modified string is the one in the database :(

Comment: Then the string that is passed as argument already contains those chars, and the bug is in code you're not showing us.

Comment: No, as you can see I print out the content of the original string before printing out the whole SQL command (last two lines in the code)

Comment: My guess is that your string contains invisible characters that don't exist in the database's character encoding. Try to dump every char as an int and see if there are hidden characters.

Comment: should this encoding problem belong to Java's PreparedStatement ?